# Find Partition with existing path

Tags: powershell

I need to find the partition number of an external disk that contains a specific folder.

I have tried using `Get-Disk | Where-Object` and filtering by the friendly name 'MSFT Virtual Disk' however when utilizing virtual environments this approach does not work.

I believe that what I am looking for needs multiple variables strung togeather, but given i am reasonably novice with powershell I thought id ask for  opinions.

- My previous attempt used a hard coded approach, finding a virtual disk & attaching it then calling the expected partition.

```
$Foldername = Get-ChildItem E:\Media$\windowsimagebackup\$PCN\backup*
$Foldername = "E:\Media$\windowsimagebackup\$PCN\" + $Foldername.Name
$VHDName = Get-ChildItem $Foldername *.vhdx | Where-Object {$_.Length -GT 1000000000}
$VHDName = $VHDName.Name
$path = $Foldername + "\" + $VHDName

Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $path

$DiskNumber = Get-Disk | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -Eq "Msft Virtual Disk"}
$DiskNumber = $DiskNumber.Number

Set-Partition -PartitionNumber 2 -DiskNumber $DiskNumber -NewDriveLetter M
```

- What i was hoping to do is something like
- List All Active Drives

```
$Disks = Get-Disk | ##Filter the Results to display active drive letters##
```

- Test each Drive to see if a path exists

```
$Test = Test-Path $Disk.Driveletter\$Path
```

- Set a variable for the disk & partition that contains the path required
- Some form of error catching in case the script finds 2 disks that match the path

Comment: Knock, knock man. RU OK w/ any of the answers delivered? If yes and you expect to have gotten help in the future, a feedback is is a good habit here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are more looking for volumes `Get-Volume` :

```
DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
C                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    106.67 GB 465.21 GB
L                        Unknown        CD-ROM    Healthy      Unknown                     0 B       0 B
F                        Unknown        Removable Healthy      Unknown                     0 B       0 B
G                        Unknown        Removable Healthy      Unknown                     0 B       0 B
H                        Unknown        Removable Healthy      Unknown                     0 B       0 B
K                        Unknown        Removable Healthy      Unknown                     0 B       0 B
D           Nouveau nom  NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      1.81 TB   3.46 TB
E           Nouveau nom  NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    745.83 GB   2.59 TB
J                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     45.45 MB    450 MB
```

It allows you to find available volumes.

Another way but more oriented PowerShell is to use `Get-PSDrive` filtering with `FileSystem`.

You can find more detail on volmes mounted with :

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | Format-Table Name, Label, FreeSpace, Capacity
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that something that you're looking for:

```
$dirToFind = 'directory' 
Get-Partition | 
Where-Object -FilterScript { [char]::IsLetter($_.DriveLetter) -and [bool](Get-ChildItem -Path "$($_.DriveLetter):\" -Filter "$dirToFind" -Directory -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) } |
Select-Object -Property DriveLetter
```

Please, be aware that `Get-Partition` is a cmdlet taken from the storage module that is available on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016. (Details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-partition?view=win10-ps)